# How can I create a total that is filtered by selection and slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

### Problem

I would like to create a multi-layer histogram that shows the distribution of `var1` on the first level and `var2` on the second level, with a legend by `source`, like this:

[image]

The value should show the percentage w.r.t. the total of a `source`, with all the selections and slicers applied. The percentages shown in the histogram should always sum to 100% per `source`.

### Example data

I have the following example data:

```
source  var1    var2    count
A       1       1       100
A       1       2       12
A       1       3       34
A       2       1       1612
A       2       2       23
A       2       3       43
B       1       1       200
B       1       2       320
B       1       3       12
B       2       1       1757
B       2       2       345
B       2       3       32
```

### What have I tried

I can achieve a total per `source` with the following measure **without** the filtering part:

```
percPerSource = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM(input[count]); 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(input[count]); 
        ALLEXCEPT(input;input[source])
        )
    )*100
```

[image]

If I turn on Drill mode and click on the columns of `var1` I get the following, undesired result (the percentages do not sum to 100%):

[image]

Another attempt was using the `ALLSELECTED` function:

```
percSelected = 
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(input[count]); 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(input[count]); 
            ALLSELECTED(input[var1])
            )
        )*100
```

This shows only 100% on the `var2` level:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do what you're after:

```
percPerSource = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM(input[count]);
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(input[count]);
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(input);
            input[Source] IN VALUES(input[Source])
        )
    )
)*100
```

This takes all the selected values as the universe you are filtering on but only selects the rows that in your local filter context.

[image: Drilldown]

---

The [`FILTER` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax) takes a table as its first argument and a condition as the second argument. It iterates through every row in the table passed into it and checks if the condition holds and returns a table with only the rows where the condition evaluates to `True`.

The `VALUES` function returns a list of distinct values of the column specified evaluated within the local filter context.

Comment: It works, thanks! I don't follow though how the `FILTER` works. Could you please add a little explanation on that? The VALUES just returns the unique `sources`, so to me it seems `source in UNIQUE(source)` will always be true?